# PHP/JSON array sorting by highest number - Riot API

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I am currently playing with Riot Games API and using one of the wrappers developed by the community (https://github.com/kevinohashi/php-riot-api). My issue is, I am trying to sort the results using arsort

My code example:

```
<?php
include('php-riot-api.php');

$summoner_name = 'fallingmoon';
$summoner_id = 24381045;

$test = new riotapi('euw');

$r = $test->getLeague($summoner_id);

?>

<?php

$array = json_decode($r, true); 

foreach($array AS $key => $newArray) {
$tempArray[$key] = $newArray['entries'][0]['leaguePoints'];
}

arsort($tempArray);
$finalArray = array();

foreach($tempArray AS $key => $value) {
$finalArray[] = $array[$key];
}

?>
```

My goal is sort the array by league points (Highest to lowest), but the output of the array once I print it is as followed, as you can see it hasn't sorted. I am probably missing something very minor but any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[name] => Rengar's Demolishers
[tier] => GOLD
[queue] => RANKED_SOLO_5x5
[entries] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[playerOrTeamId] => 33372844
[playerOrTeamName] => L3tsPl4yLoL
[leagueName] => Rengar's Demolishers
[queueType] => RANKED_SOLO_5x5
[tier] => GOLD
[rank] => V
[leaguePoints] => 0
[wins] => 34
[isHotStreak] => 1
[isVeteran] => 
[isFreshBlood] => 
[isInactive] => 
[lastPlayed] => -1
)

[1] => Array
(
[playerOrTeamId] => 19397582
[playerOrTeamName] => Lunchi
[leagueName] => Rengar's Demolishers
[queueType] => RANKED_SOLO_5x5
[tier] => GOLD
[rank] => IV
[leaguePoints] => 10
[wins] => 7
[isHotStreak] => 
[isVeteran] => 
[isFreshBlood] => 
[isInactive] => 
[lastPlayed] => -1
)

[2] => Array
(
[playerOrTeamId] => 24613501
[playerOrTeamName] => RadiantBurst
[leagueName] => Rengar's Demolishers
[queueType] => RANKED_SOLO_5x5
[tier] => GOLD
[rank] => II
[leaguePoints] => 42
[wins] => 48
[isHotStreak] => 
[isVeteran] => 
[isFreshBlood] => 
[isInactive] => 
[lastPlayed] => -1
)

[3] => Array
(
[playerOrTeamId] => 19939979
[playerOrTeamName] => vinter
[leagueName] => Rengar's Demolishers
[queueType] => RANKED_SOLO_5x5
[tier] => GOLD
[rank] => I
[leaguePoints] => 38
[wins] => 57
[isHotStreak] => 
[isVeteran] => 
[isFreshBlood] => 
[isInactive] => 
[lastPlayed] => -1
)
```

Comment: What does the `$tempArray` look like?

Comment: it just prints the following:

    Array
    (
    [24381045] => 0
    )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `$array` is an array with one array in it.

Presumably you want to sort the entries array in which case you can tweak your code:

```
foreach($array[0]['entries'] AS $key => $team) {
    $tempArray[$key] = $team['leaguePoints'];
}

arsort($tempArray);
$finalArray = array();

foreach($tempArray AS $key => $value) {
    $finalArray[] = $array[0]['entries'][$key];
}
```

Note that the above doesn't support multiple leagues.

However I find using `usort` to be more readable:

```
foreach($array as $key => $league){
    usort($array[$key]['entries'], function($a,$b){
        return $a['leaguePoints'] - $b['leaguePoints'];
    });
}
```

Comment: the usort function worked a treat, the downside is the number of league points is listed in the array from lowest to highest - what would be the ideal sorting method for highest to lowest?

Comment: @DanWhiteside You can either switch to `ursort` or change the compare function to `return $b['leaguePoints'] - $a['leaguePoints'];`.

Comment: Just changed the compare function and was about to do what you suggested! Works a charm - the rest of the code I have planned is plain sailing, Many thanks Jim once again.

Comment: I am using the tweaked code above with a similar array (example of output [link](http://pastebin.com/skZ4M8Mk) from the same API - one of the errors is Cannot use a scalar value as an array and the other is usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: @DanWhiteside That means you are passing `null` to `usort`. Check that the first argument is what you intend it to be.